# Is a view required to use ajax?

Tags: ajax, django

I'm migrating a site to django, and part of that is some ajax calls to php scripts. All I keep getting back from my ajax calls are the contents of the php file, not the results of the script being executed.

Not sure if this is because I'm only using the django dev server (project not in a folder processed by apache) or if I need url.py and views.py entries for the ajax call...

My ajax call from my js file:

```
function getLab(labId) {
  let data = new Object();
  data['ID'] = labId;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/static/php/fetchLab.php",
    type: "get",
    data: data,
    success: getLabFinish
  });
}
```

And the response is the contents of the php file:

```
<?php
  require('/static/php/log.php');
  require('/static/php/config.php');
  $log = new Log();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, something must take this PHP script(s) and pass them to an PHP interpreter. Otherwise you receive the script as text, as the server threats them like that. You might have encountered the same effect when you serve PHP files with a webserver that is not configured with PHP properly.

Your guess regarding apache isn't that wrong. You might configure a local apache with the PHP module enabled to receive their desired output.

This approach might be sufficient while migrating, but it is definitely not recommended as a result of your migration.

As a workaround you might also replace the PHP script with dummy output and provide them in the static folder. This way you can already prepare other parts of your application and migrate them later.

As already mentioned you want to end up with corresponding views in your django project.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what dahrens and Jerin Peter George have said.  It definitely sounds like you do not have PHP installed on the server, which wouldn't be needed in a python/django environment.  Therefore the ajax request is getting back text from the php file.

I will add some context for you to get an idea of what an ajax request and response would look like in django 2.x

**in your javascript (frontend)**

```
    $.ajax({
           url: '/save/json/',
           method: 'POST',
           data: {"data":"content"}
   })
```

**in your views.py**

```
def save_json(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            incoming_json_data = json.loads(request.body)
            # DO STUFF WITH THE JSON DATA
    HttpResponse("OK")
```

**in your urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('save/json/', views.save_json),
]
```